# Haversine Formula - Results Too High

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geolocation, coordinates, haversine

I am using the Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points on earth. I have the following code:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var myLat, myLon, locLat, locLon;
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(GetLocation)

  $scope.ASiteLocs = [{
    "name": "IL5077 BRUSSELS",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.58543899999999,38.955472,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5076 KAMPSVILLE",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.661923,39.29403,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5146 CARROLLTON",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.39965700000001,39.309142,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5153 GREENFIELD",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.208747,39.364077,0"
    }
  }];
  $scope.SSiteLocs = [];
  $scope.SiteLocs = $scope.SSiteLocs.concat($scope.ASiteLocs);
  repoSortOrder = "site.name";


  function GetLocation(location, myLat, myLon) {
    myLat = location.coords.latitude;
    myLon = location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = myLat;
     document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = myLon;
    $timeout(function() {
      calculate();
    });

  }

  $scope.getCoordDistance = function(myLat, myLon, locLat, locLon) {
    var lat1 = locLat; //41.887055
    var lon1 = locLon; //-88.469233
    var lat2 = myLat; //41.888668
    var lon2 = myLon; //-87.640371

    var R = 3959;
    var x1 = lat2 - lat1;
    var dLat = x1 * Math.PI / 180;
    var x2 = lon2 - lon1;
    var dLon = x2 * Math.PI / 180;
    a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d;

  };


  angular.forEach($scope.SSiteLocs, function(object) {
    object.carrier = 'Sprint';
  });
  angular.forEach($scope.ASiteLocs, function(object) {
    object.carrier = 'AT&T';
  });
var i = 0;
locX = 1;
  var calculate = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location) {
      var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;
      if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength - 2, clength) === ",0") {
        location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
        Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
        Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
        Com = ",";
        location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com, Lat);
      myLat = Number(document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML)
      myLon = Number(document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML)

      locLat = Lat;
      locLon = Lon;
      d = $scope.getCoordDistance(myLat, myLon, locLat, locLon);
      location.distance = d.toFixed(1);

    if(i < 15){
      console.log("********LOCATON " + locX + "***********")
      console.log("myCoords: " + myLat + "," + myLon);
      console.log("locCoords: " + locLat + "," + locLon);

      console.log("d: " + d);
      console.log("***************************")
      i++;
      locX++;

    }
    }

    });
  };


});
```

The results from the formula are up to about 9-10 thousand when they should be no where near that high. If I use the commented out coordinates it returns correctly (42.6 Miles)
Since the test coordinates work I know it is not a math problem. Does anybody know what is causing the formula to not work correctly?
**EDIT** 
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nRQc7Ym0lsaK6jQwd626?p=preview) is a plunker of the full proj. if that helps. 
 **EDIT2** 
 I discovered something odd, the results are different in different browsers, so, chrome displays one set of numbers and IE displays another, ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your point coordinates are longitude latitude

```
BRUSSELS",
    "
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.58543899999999,38.955472
```

In your code

```
Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
```

Either change them in your object(preferable) See Google [**latlng class**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

```
"Point": {
          "coordinates": "38.955472,-90.58543899999999
```

or

```
Lat = location.Point.coordinates[1];
Lon = location.Point.coordinates[0];
```

With your settings distance is aprox 9000 miles with coordinates transposed distance is aprox 200

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, here, without testing it but it looks like the GetLocation function is overwriting the closure scope of the variables myLat and myLon by declaring them as function arguments, so you're assigning the value of location.coords.latitude into the function scope myLat variable, instead of the myLat declared at the beginning of your code block.

throw a console.log(myLat, myLon); into the beginning of getCoordDistance and check their values. I'll bet they're not what you expect.

edit: it actually may have been the lack of semicolons and stuff. here's a small snippet of your code re-calibrated to run in an isolated environment like jsbin.com. It appears to work fine. you were missing 4 semicolons, so unless this assignment is failing, it should work: myLon = Number(document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML)

there were complaints of variable "i" and "locX" not being defined

```
var myLat, myLon;

var ASiteLocs = [{
    "name": "IL5077 BRUSSELS",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.58543899999999,38.955472,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5076 KAMPSVILLE",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.661923,39.29403,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5146 CARROLLTON",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.39965700000001,39.309142,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5153 GREENFIELD",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.208747,39.364077,0"
    }
  }];

var SSiteLocs = [];
var SiteLocs = SSiteLocs.concat(ASiteLocs);

function GetLocation(location, myLat, myLon) {
    myLat = location.coords.latitude;
    myLon = location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = myLat;
     document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = myLon;

  }

function getCoordDistance(myLat, myLon, locLat, locLon) {
    var lat1 = locLat; //41.887055
    var lon1 = locLon; //-88.469233
    var lat2 = myLat; //41.888668
    var lon2 = myLon; //-87.640371

    var R = 3959;
    var x1 = lat2 - lat1;
    var dLat = x1 * Math.PI / 180;
    var x2 = lon2 - lon1;
    var dLon = x2 * Math.PI / 180;
    a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d;

  };


function calculate() {
    SiteLocs.forEach(function(location) {
      var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;
      if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength - 2, clength) === ",0") {
        location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
        Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
        Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
        Com = ",";
        location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com, Lat);
      myLat = -90.208747;
      myLon = 39.364077;

      locLat = Lat;
      locLon = Lon;
      d = getCoordDistance(myLat, myLon, locLat, locLon);
      location.distance = d.toFixed(1);

    //console.log("********LOCATON " + locX + "***********");
      console.log("myCoords: " + myLat + "," + myLon);
      console.log("locCoords: " + locLat + "," + locLon);

      console.log("d: " + d);
      console.log("***************************");

    }

    });
  };
```

Comment: `myLat` and `myLon` are the values expected at `getCoordDistance` so I do not think that is it. Thank you though!

Comment: can you provide me with the four values that getCoordDistance is getting called with?

Comment: `myLat` and `myLon` are coordinates from `navigate.geolocation.eatchPosition` and `locLat` and `locLon` are from `coordinates` in `$scope.ASiteLocs`

Comment: I imported your code into a test environment and edited it, there were some semicolon problems, but it seems to work

Comment: What were some of the results in the table for distance?

Comment: and how did you test it?

Comment: fyi, here's a link to the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jofaxudahube/3/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what kirinthos said in his response, you can easily test this by comparing your results with Google Maps. I have a function in my app that does this. The point1 and point2 parameters are simple Latlng objects.I wanted the results in kilometers so I divide by 1000.

```
function calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(point1, point2) {
    return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
}
```

You'll need the following in your HTML page:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,places"></script>
```

Comment: I believe the script tag has a typo in it.